# JsColor doesn't open in Chrome, in Firefox works ok

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, jscolor

Im using [JSColor](http://jscolor.com/) as colorpicker for my site, I had few issues with losing its instance after postback because of Update Panel but found solution for that in other question:

```
 private void RegisterClientStartupScript(string scriptKey, string scriptText)
    {
        ScriptManager sManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);

        if (sManager != null && sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            //if a MS AJAX request, use the Scriptmanager class
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, true);
        }
        else
        {
            //if a standard postback, use the standard ClientScript method
            scriptText = string.Concat("Sys.Application.add_load(function(){", scriptText, "});");
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), scriptKey, scriptText, true);
        }
```

and using it in page_load like this fixed the problem:

```
RegisterClientStartupScript("some", "jscolor.init();");
```

Now I got it to work perfectly in Firefox but in Chrome it doesn't even open when I press button, here is how it's set up in markup:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
```

in body:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtButtonTextColorSample" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtButtonTextColor" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtButtonTextColor_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <input type="button" id="fontCPicker" value="Pick" class="color {valueElement:'txtButtonTextColor',styleElement:'txtButtonTextColorSample',hash:true,required:false}" />
                                        <input type="button" onclick=" doPostBackAsync('<%= txtButtonTextColor.ClientID %>', 'OnTextChanged');" value="Apply" />
```

It should show when button "fontCPicker" but nothing happens, I don't see any errors in Chrome console but I'm not sure if it's really debugging or not because I don't use Chrome often.

Comment: Where is your `click` event listener for `fontCPicker`?

Comment: @Nick take a look at the link of JSColor it should work just by specyfing class="color" on the element which you want to bound to dialog,imported js file does the rest, and as I said It works fine in Firefox

Comment: Try example #7 on this page and let me know if it works in Chrome: http://jscolor.com/try.php

Comment: @Nick I don't know how but it worked in chrome, what am I doing wrong with my example?

Comment: What does `{valueElement:'txtButtonTextColor',styleElement:'txtButtonTextColorSample',hash:true,required:false}` return?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that it did not interfere with your `class="color"` declaration. The only declarations that jsColor requires are an `input` with `class="color"` and a `script` declaration to the js file itself. Therefore, the only thing that I can think of is maybe your C# code is returning something illegal.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try working with basic example without adding ton of tags like in my code,maybe it will work, at least I know #7 demo works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was indeed wrong with lot of options that I've put in class attribute, so I replaced it with only basic options.